# Rubymine does not detect folder directories in Rails Application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ide, directory, rubymine-7

This happened right after i did a restart; Ruby mine detects files at root directory but does not detect folders.

[image]
[image]

What caused this? What should I do to fix it?

Comment: Check in the bottom right corner if Rubymine is indexing - it recursively searches through the folders and files and since it runs in the JVM it sometimes just takes forever.

Answer (score 3):

Not sure what's causing this, but you can close RubyMine, delete .idea folder of your project and reopen it.

Comment: I just had this problem following an upgrade and this fixed it for me.